# JavaScript redirect not working and works only in Chrome if debugger is turned on

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with the following javascript code to redirect on "success"?

```
$('#recordUser').click(function () {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/RecordUser',
    data: $("#recordUserForm").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (userEmail) {
        var newUrl = "/Home/AnotherPage?email=" + userEmail.Email;
        $(location).attr('href', newUrl);
        //I have also tried following ways to redirect:
        //window.location.href = "/Home/AnotherPage?email=" + userEmail.Email;
        //window.location = "/Home/AnotherPage?email=" + userEmail.Email;
        //window.location.replace(newUrl);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(xhr);            
    }
 });
});
//#recordUser is a button inside a form with method="post"
```

**Html** for the form:

```
       <form id="recordUserForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <div class="...">
         <input id="recordUserEmail" class="span6" name="Email" type="text">
        </div>
        <button class="..." id="recordUser">Submit</button>
       </form>
```

I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox and the redirect does not happen on both. I have already made sure that my server code is working fine.

In Chrome, if I run the javascript in debug mode then the page is redirected with any of the redirect commands but if I close the debugger the redirect commands stop working.

If I remove the "method" attribute from my html form then the query string in the url does appear but the page stays on the same location. For example if I was at localhost:80 and then submit the form then the url changes to localhost:80?email=email instead of the expected newUrl. Strangely if I run this in debug then it works as expected. Why?

Would be thankful/happy if someone could point out the mistake and the reason why above code is only working in Chrome debug mode? I would also like to find out how I can get a useful error message to be printed out in my "error" callback? By useful I mean something which points me to the source of the error (eg an exception message, stack trace etc.) and not something that I have to insert manually.

**UPDATE 1**

If I change the html for button to

```
        <input class="..." id="recordUser" value="Submit" type="button"/>
```

and use the click method in the script then it works fine.

I would still appreciate an answer informing me how to get it working with `button` and why the script was working in Chrome debug mode?

**UPDATE 2**

While posting Update1 I realized that I was missing the `type` in the html for `button`. Maybe, I thought that because it is marked as a `button` then specifyin the type would be redundant but it is not.

```
 <button type="button" class="..." id="recordUser">Submit</button>
```

The above markup with the original javascript now works as expected. So, I guess the only question is why it worked in Chrome debug mode then?

Comment: Removed my answer - I don't have time to debug it properly

Answer (score 0):

If `window.location = "something"` fails that is because one of two possibilities:

1. The code is not being executed because your ajax query is not succeeding (can be some problem with your back end, use console.log at the beginning of the success function in order to detect if it gets executed).
2. "something" is exactly the same url that is currently in your browser navigation bar, so it actually is working.

Don't use these because they are completely wrong (the other two methods are correct):

- $(location).attr('href', newUrl);
- window.location.replace(newUrl);

The correct methods for redirecting are these (either will work crossbrowser):

- window.location = "something";
- window.location.href = "something";

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. I had updated the question about the same time when you answered. Have a look at the end of the question.