# Javascript redirect only seems to work when chrome debugger is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I have written a Jquery-Ui Dialog to popup as a confirmation on particular links. This however does not redirect to my Delete page correctly. However if I open the debugger in chrome to debug, then the code works as expected.

I have found the same question, however the solution does not seem to work for me. It is exactly the same scenario though. Question here [JavaScript redirect not working and works only in Chrome if debugger is turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257119/javascript-redirect-not-working-and-works-only-in-chrome-if-debugger-is-turned-o)

So I have my link

```
<div id="confirm-dialog">
    <div class="dialog-inner">
        <p id="confirm-dialog-message"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="/Customer/Delete/73865878346587" class="confirmLink" title="Delete Customer" data-confirm-message="Are you sure you want to delete this customer?">Delete</a>
```

And I have my javascript

```
    $('.confirmLink').click(function (e) {
    BodyScrolling(false);

    var theHref = $(this).attr("href");
    var theTitle = $(this).attr("title") == null ? "Confirm..." : $(this).attr("title");
    var theText = $(this).attr("data-confirm-message") == null ? "Are you sure?" : $(this).attr("data-confirm-message");

    $("#confirm-dialog-message").html(theText);
    $("#confirm-dialog").parent().css({ position: "fixed" }).end().dialog("open");
    $("#confirm-dialog").dialog({
        title: theTitle,
        close: function() {
            BodyScrolling(true);
        },
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Yes",
            class: "mws-button red",
            click: function () {
                $("#confirm-dialog").dialog("close");
                window.location.href = theHref;
                return false;
            }
        },
        {
            text: "No",
            class: "mws-button black",
            click: function () {
                $("#confirm-dialog").dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });
    return false;
});
```

So when I click my Delete link, I am indeed presented with my confirm dialog with Yes and No buttons, css styled correctly, and has captured the link href and bound it to the Yes button. If I click "No", I am kicked back and nothing further happens - Correct!

If I click Yes, it should take send me on to the original href that it captured. I have thrown alert(theHref) on the Yes Button click just before the redirect and it does show me the correct address (/Customer/Delete/73865878346587), but the redirect does not happen.

When I open the chrome debugger to debug the javascript or see if any errors occurred, then everything works as expected and redirects me correctly!

In IE, it does not work either.

I have tried...

```
window.location.href = theHref
window.location = theHref
location.href = theHref
$(location).attr('href', theHref)
```

I have also tried adding return false; after my redirect. Nothing works.

The link I added above to the same question said to make sure that the Yes button is being rendered on the page as a ... which mine is.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: What about other browsers? See response from @Th3BFG, window.location = url, or window.location.assign(url).

Comment: I've tried chrome, ie 8,9,10, Firefox. I've tried the other suggestions and still nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found the answer. Javascript was a red herring!

I did try to remove the confirmLink jQuery class so that the link was just a standard link that went straight to my controller to perofm my delete. When I did this test, the link worked perfectly. Therefore I denoted the problem be with my javascript. However, it seems that this was not quite the case and had only worked again if the Debugger in Chrome had been or was open at the time aswell.

When I revisited the non confirm link option again, I found this not to work properly, therefore denoting the problem not with the javascript.

It appears that you cannot perform a Delete action from a HTML Link in MVC. This is obviously because of security risks involved as anyone could perform a Delete on an Id. I had thought of this in my implementation and had added code to check where the Request had come from and if it wasn't from my List page, then it threw back an error and wouldn't perform the Delete. It didn't matter what I named my controller either, eg Test, the link performing my HTTP GET request would never hit this. There must be some algorithm that determines what the action is doing and stops you from performing the action on a HttpGet request. For more information about Delete Actions, check out this post http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because

It seems that you can only perform this by a HTTP Post, which means either using a `Ajax.ActionLink` or by using a Form and a submit button. Then your Action must be specified for HttpPost.

If, like me, you wish to keep your Link as a HTML Link, then you can do the following which is what I did, code below. I kept my HTML Link, set it up to point to my HttpPost Delete Action. Added my confirmLink class for jquery to bind my dialog box to. I pick up the link href and set the Yes button in the jquery dialog to dynamically create a Form and set the method to post and the action to the links href. Then I can call submit on the new dynamically created form to perform my Post to my Delete action.

My Delete Link

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Caterer", new { id = caterer.Id }, new { @class = "mws-ic-16 ic-delete imageButton confirmLink", @data_confirm_title = "Delete " + caterer.Name, @data_confirm_message = "Are you sure you want to delete this caterer, " + caterer.Name + "?" })
```

My Javascript

```
function LoadConfirm() {
    $('.confirmLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        BodyScrolling(false);

        var actionHref = $(this).attr("href");
        var confirmTitle = $(this).attr("data-confirm-title");
        confirmTitle = confirmTitle == null ? "Confirm..." : confirmTitle;

        var confirmMessage = $(this).attr("data-confirm-message");
        confirmMessage = confirmMessage == null ? "Are you sure?" : confirmMessage;

        $("#confirm-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            close: function () { BodyScrolling(true); },
            title: confirmTitle,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: [
            {
                text: "Yes",
                class: "mws-button red",
                click: function () {
                    StartLoading();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    var form = document.createElement("form");
                    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
                    form.setAttribute("action", actionHref);
                    form.submit();
                }
            },
            {
                text: "No",
                class: "mws-button black",
                click: function () {
                    $("#confirm-dialog").dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            ]
        });
        $("#confirm-dialog #confirm-dialog-message").html(confirmMessage);
        $("#confirm-dialog").parent().css({ position: "fixed" });
        $("#confirm-dialog").dialog("open");
    });
}
```

My Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "User")]
    public ActionResult Delete(long id)
    {
        //Perform my delete

        return RedirectToActionPermanent("List");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.location.href = theHref;`

have you tried `window.location.replace(theHref);`?

Back to basics, try: `window.location = theHref;`

Comment: Ok, here are some reasons as to why window.location = url doesn't work. The idea here is that it should, with ALL modern browsers.

- They have JavaScript disabled.

- Their browser doesn't support accessing just location by itself, you should use window.location.

- You should specify the protocol (i.e. http:// or https://) in your window.location, just using mydomain.com could translate as /mydomain.com in certain browsers.

- Make sure that the full address is being passed to the window.location function.

- ETC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is still being developed not a bug. I have JS enabled in my browsers, I know the URL works fine and I expect it to be a relative path as it is not going elsewhere outside of my domain, it is just a link to another MVC Action in my site. I can confirm the link href that Javascript picks up is correct as expected. And most importantly, this works perfectly fine when the chrome debugger window is open. In the link i posted as part of my question, someone else mentions that their button had no type which was their issue. It must be something to do with my layout.